# There is Short way in JavaScript to run now function and in Specific interval

Tags: javascript

Some times, I want to run something now and in the future.

Is there any short way for that?

```
var myFunctionName = function(){
  alert('ok');
  alert('I want this to run now, and after every 100ms');
}
setInterval(a, 100);
myFunctionName();
```

Comment: 1. Your fragment is messy and wrong, please fix. 2 What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any function can return itself. Then you can run it inside the setInterval, wirthout giving it any name..

```
setInterval((function(){
alert('ok');
alert('I want this to run now, and after every 100ms')
return (arguments.callee)
})(),100)
```

Comment: Not a good idea at all, and not standard. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)